# apache http-basic-auth

Tags: apache-httpd

can someone please tell me what `apache http-basic-auth`is ?

```
This is an example configuration for an apache ($ENV{REMOTE_USER})
# auth. backend. Use it if you want to have a singe login through
# apache http-basic-auth
$Self->{'AuthModule'} = 'Kernel::System::Auth::HTTPBasicAuth';
# Note:
#
# If you use this module, you should use as fallback
# the following configuration settings if the user is not authorized
# apache ($ENV{REMOTE_USER})
$Self->{LoginURL} = 'http://host.example.com/not-authorised-for-otrs.html';
$Self->{LogoutURL} = 'http://host.example.com/thanks-for-using-otrs.html';
```

I don't see it [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html)

Answer (score 1):

It says **HTTP**-basic-auth not **HTTPd**-basic-auth.

You have to search [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) documentation non [HTTPd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) one.

The HTTP basic authentication is defined in [RFC7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617) but, probably, you can start with the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Obviously, Apache HTTPd supports http-basic-auth. You can find Apache implementation details [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html)